# Time formating troubles in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

So i have my date in this format:

> 2014-02-15 16:38:30

And, that's how I'm trying to format it:

```
<?php echo $this->Time->format('F jS h:i A', $job->created); ?>
```

And the error:

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (F jS hh:i A) at
>   position 5 (h): Double timezone specification

How can I fix this Double timezone thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the api for the right arguments of the TimeHelper format function:

http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.View.Helper.TimeHelper.html#_format

As you can se there, the first argument should be the data, and not the format. Moreover, it is better to just use the date object instead of the helper, for example:

```
echo $job->create
```

The date formatted there is controller by the the specified format as explained here:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#formatting

You can for example do

```
echo $job->created->nice();
```

Comment: But for all non-required datetime fields you should first check on `if ($job->fieldname)`, otherwise it is a fatal exception as `->nice()` doesn't like to work on `null` ;) The nicer way IMO still would be to use the TimeHelper which handles this internally.